# How to stop the Viber process?

Tags: viber-messenger

I have an HTC Desire S II.

I use Viber only occasionally. To save battery, I want to "kill" it when not in use. The menu has an `Exit` button that seems to work, but Viber still comes back to life after a while.

Is there any way to make it stay "dead" without uninstalling it?

Comment: Can you not issue a "Force Stop" on the app info screen?

Comment: Probably.. I was hoping for a less brutal way. But hey, I just killed it this way. Remains to verify that it stays dead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't possible, since Viber needs to be running in order to receive calls which are routed via Viber. If you shut down the background process, you can't be reached via Viber. The exit button just means it closes the UI, but keeps listening for calls in the background.

Comment: Ok, tnx. But... what if this is what I _want_? To stop listening for incoming calls. If I expect a call, I'll simply restart it.

Comment: then again, force close it.

Answer (score 5):

This is a member of the Viber R&D Team. I'm here to assist :)

Viber has an "Exit" option, inside the "More" tab. After choosing this option, Viber should shut down completely, and not leave a process running. It can still stay available for calls and texts with the help of the C2DM service, that "awakens" Viber upon incoming calls and texts.

Comment: Wow, it's amazing to have someone from the Viber team on Android.se. I hope you're real! :D

Comment: Haha... of course we're real ;)

We reach out to many different forums/blogs across the world, providing direct assistance to our users.